# Finding range of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been trying to find range of this $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ function:
$$f(z) = z+2\overline{z}+z\cdot\overline{z}+iz$$
I tried writing it out as:
$$c+di =a+bi-2a-2bi+a^2+b^2+ai-b$$
Sadly I somehow can't get past that. What should I do now to get my solution? I am not sure how do I properly get solution for $a$ and $b$ (how can I get the two separate equations which will lead to solution)

Answer (score 1):

A complex function $f:z \in \mathbb{C} \mapsto f(z)\in \mathbb{C}$ can be interpreted as a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2} $:

$$g:(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto g((a,b))=(c,d)\in \mathbb{R}^2$$

Where $z=a+bi$ and $f(z)=c+di$. By simplifying the expression you gave for $c+di$ (there is a sign error for the complex conjugate summand) the following relation is obtained:

$$(c,d)=(3a+a^2+b^2-b,a-b)$$

The image of the function g is now given by the set:

$$\mathrm{Image}(g)=\{(c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^2:\exists(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ \mathrm{such\ that}\ g((a,b))=(c,d)\}$$

In other words: In order to determine $\mathrm{Image}(g)$ you need to determine the real-value pairs $(c,d)$ for which the equation $(c,d)=(3a+a^2+b^2-b,a-b)$ has a solution $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Try to solve this equation algebraically for $a(c,d)$ and $b(c,d)$ and then determine for which $c$ and $d$ the solutions are real.